# Laggy gif in java when displaying

Tags: java, gif, lag

So basically I am trying to  render an animated gif but, it looks stuttery, and laggy. I have no clue what the issue might be.

```
public class TestDraw {

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.addComponentListener(null);
            Image ability = new ImageIcon(PNGDef.class.getResource("characters/ability.gif")).getImage();
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ability);
            try {
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(icon));
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the gif in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zAE3.gif)

Comment: AWT and Swing code is supposed to run in the AWT event dispatch thread.  Failing to do so can cause strange an unexpected behavior.  Also, you don’t need to create two ImageIcons.  One ImageIcon is sufficient.

Comment: The gif seems to play fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VGR is correct. This is pretty much identical to the behaviour I get when viewing the gif in a browser:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class F extends JFrame {
    private void setGui() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Container cp = getContentPane();
            cp.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("test.gif")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    F f = new F();
                    f.setGui();
                    f.pack();
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```